# Permission denied when cloning git repo through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

From a server (A) I launch a script called test.sh which contains this code :

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh login@server-b.com -p 22 'bash $HOME/tmp/git.sh'

exit 0
```

So from server (B) another script is launched (called git.sh) and contains :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/tmp
git clone ssh://repo_login@my-repo.com:22/home/scripts

exit 0
```

But the git clone does not work and I get this error message :

```
Cloning into 'scripts'...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But from server (B) If I launch the git.sh script manually, it works.

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks
L.

Comment: Do you have an appropriate private key on server B?

If so, does it have the appropriate permissions? Should be -rw------- (chmod 600). The .ssh folder itself should have drwx------ (chmod 700).

Comment: Did you check if the relevant environment variables are the same?  I would guess that they would be different since the shell is interactive when you are running the script manually and non interactive otherwise. https://superuser.com/a/183980/161384

Comment: You probably need to start the `ssh-agent` process and add the key manually when on ssh: `eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: @DanielSmith : yes, private key is on server B with appropriate permissions.

Comment: @Satyaanveshi : I'm not using environment variables when I run those scripts, I don't need them.

Comment: @user000001 : I'm using a shared server, so I do not have access to systemctl commands

Comment: @TooNetCreation: These commands are executed as the user, not as root, just  add them in `git.sh` file right before the `git clone` command

Comment: @user000001 : just to be sure, do you have a sample of the full command line (to avoid erros)?

Comment: @TooNetCreation: Just added an answer to show how the script should be modified

Answer (score 1):

When running a script through `ssh`, you need to start the ssh-agent, and add your keys before you can connect to another machine.

Script `git.sh` should be modified as below (assuming your key is in file `~/.ssh/id_rsa`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd $HOME/tmp
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
git clone ssh://repo_login@my-repo.com:22/home/scripts
exit 0
```

Comment: same problem, I get this error : Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @TooNetCreation: That's a different error ("Host key verification failed" vs the original "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive)."). It indicates that an earlier attempt to get ssh access to the machine recorded the machine's "I really am the machine you're trying to access" key/password/whatever-you-would-like-to-call-it. So now server B knows how to make sure that `my-repo.com` is who they claim to be. Server B called up `my-repo.com` this time and they had a *different key* so they must not be the same machine after all. Obviously, [continued]

Comment: Obviously Server B had better not trust the liars responding at `my-repo.com`! So Server-B doesn't, and instead gives you the "Host key verification failed" message. If you're sure that the liars at `my-repo.com` aren't lying, you'd best tell Server B that the host key it recorded is out of date, or to stop recording host keys at all, or something, so that they trust the liars there. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will have a look